# Read file and save it in memory

Tags: c#, performance, caching, memory

My application uses a custom .xml settings file which I read some stuff from. As it is now it reads from the file every time and it effects performance. What is the best way of save the file into the cache and read from there instead?

```
public static class SettingsReader {
    private static XDocument SettingsFile = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Settings.xml");
}
```

Comment: use the static variable and on read check if that variable is null read from file

Comment: Read everything (deserialize `Settings` class) or organize cache if data are too big to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually declare a settings class. Then at startup I read configuration file and deserialize it into a Settings object and keep it in a static variable.

This way you can reach to your settings just by accessing a property from everywhere.

```
public class MySettings {
    public string RemoteServerAddress { get; set; }
    public int TcpCommunicationTimeout { get; set; }
}

public class Program {
    public readonly static MySettings ProgramSettings { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
        using(var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("config file path")){
            Program.ProgramSettings = (MySettings)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        SomeMethod();
    }

    static void SomeMethod(){
        if (Program.ProgramSettings.TcpCommunicationTimeout > 5) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```