# loading directory paths from XML

Tags: c#, xml

It's really annoying for me when I must use XML to do some things.
I have a simple `settings.xml` file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <source>H:\Źródło</source>
  <target>H:\Cel</target>
</settings>
```

I need to load source to string `sourcedir` and target to string `targetdir`.

But that's not the end, I need to make it work with copying dir from source to target, but I can't do it simply like `@+sourcedir` or `"@"+sourcedir` because it doesn't work.

I tried many times and read a lot on the web and still can't do it.

Comment: What's the question? You want to know how to read the document XmlSerializer or XmlDocument?

Comment: I want a simpliest working way to do it, no matter what i use.

Comment: You could do it like this, keep in mind that the MemoryStream is just the replacement for the filestream at that time: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYYKvd

Comment: You only posted one set of settings.  Can you update sample to include a few source/target in same file?

Comment: I think you need to read settings from XML in an easy way. This answer might solve your problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449384/read-file-and-save-it-in-memory/36450007#36450007